# SQL query for join with condition

Tags: sql

I have these two tables:

```
Customers: Id, Name
Orders: Id, CustomerId, Time, Status
```

I want to get a list of customers for which the LAST order does not have a status of 'Wrong'.

I know how to use a LEFT JOIN to get a count of orders for each customer, but I don't know how I can use this statement for what I want. Maybe a JOIN is not the right thing to use too, I'm not sure.

It's possible that customers do not have any order, and they should be returned.

I'm abstracting the real tables here, but the scenario is for a windows phone app sending notifications. I want to get all clients for which their last notification does not have a 'Dropped' status. I can sort their notifications (orders) by the 'Time' field. Thanks for the help, while I continue experimenting with subqueries in the where clause.

Comment: @user470473 You have to define what LAST means ... does it mean the highest id record, the most recent dated order ... details plz  ... also helps if you provide a set of sample data that you would like it to look like.

Comment: By LAST, I mean "order by Time desc", the most recent order according to the Time field, for [this customer] (not the last order for all customers).

Comment: What database product and version?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. Going through the proposed answers now! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select ...
From Customers As C
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From Orders As O1
                        Join    (
                                Select O2.CustomerId, Max( O2.Time ) As Time 
                                From Orders As O2
                                Group By O2.CustomerId
                                ) As LastOrderTime
                            On LastOrderTime.CustomerId = O1.CustomerId
                                And LastOrderTime.Time = O1.Time
                    Where O1.Status = 'Dropped'
                        And O1.CustomerId = C.Id
                    )
```

There are obviously alternatives based on the actual database product and version. For example, in SQL Server one could use the TOP command or a CTE perhaps. However, without knowing what specific product is being used, the above solution should produce the results you want in almost any database product.

**Addition**

If you were using a product that supported ranking functions (which database product and version isn't mentioned) and common-table expressions, then an alternative solution might be something like so:

```
With RankedOrders As
    (
    Select O.CustomerId, O.Status
        , Row_Number() Over( Partition By CustomerId Order By Time Desc ) As Rnk
    From Orders As O
    )
Select ...
From Customers
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From RankedOrders As O1
                    Where O1.CustomerId = C.Id
                        And O1.Rnk = 1
                        And O1.Status = 'Dropped'
                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Last order refers to the Time column here is my query:

```
SELECT C.Id,
       C.Name,
       MAX(O.Time)
FROM
     Customers C

  INNER JOIN Orders O 
  ON C.Id = O.CustomerId

WHERE
     O.Status != 'Wrong'

GROUP BY C.Id,
         C.Name
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding your table configuration. You should really consider revising the structure to include a third table. They would look like this:

```
Customer 
  CustomerId | Name 

Order

  OrderId  | Status | Time

CompletedOrders

  CoId  | CustomerId | OrderId
```

Now what you do is store the info about a customer or order in their respective tables ... then when an order is made you just create a CompletedOrders entry with the ids of the 2 individual records. This will allow for a 1 to Many relationship between customer and orders.

Comment: Thanks; I ended up trying out Thomas's answer first and it works for what I wanted. Something I hadn't made clear in my question is that a LEFT JOIN would be fine; I wanted to return customers that hadn't ordered before too.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check it out, but something like this?

SELECT c.CustmerId, c.Name, MAX(o.Time) 
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
WHERE o.Status <> 'Wrong'
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, C.Name

Comment: It should be inner join because it is supposed to be a list of customers for which the LAST order does not have as status code of 'Wrong'. This implies that they will have orders ... so record sets that include only customers with nulls for the order columns wouldnt be valid (results from a left join).

Comment: @Matthew Cox - He he stated in the query that they may not have an order.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of customers with the LAST order which has status of 'Wrong' with something like

select customerId from orders where status='Wrong'
 group by customerId
having time=max(time)